# Inserting dynamic html tags using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to dynamic notify when I wrote some messages.

That's my vue.js code.

```
<script>
Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true; // Send as 
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      name : "",
      postResult : ""
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {
      this.$http.post('/api/test',   {name:this.name}).then(function(response){
        var result = response.data;
        //this.postResults.push(result.name);
        if (result.name == "1234")
        {
          this.postResult = "<div> Success </div>";
        } 
        else 
        {
          this.postResult = "<div> Fail </div>";
      }
    }, function(response){
      // Error Handling
    });
  }
}
});
</script>
```

When I use jQuery's Ajax, I used this method. But my vue.js script is not working. Should I study more about Vue JS? or I forget some syntax in this vue.js?

Comment: what do you mean "But the my vue js script is not working in vue..." you are not able to see success/fail on postResult ?

Comment: @samayo Yes. that's ture. sorry I used wrong syntax.

Comment: @samayo Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Are you able to use axios? vue http is kind of obsolete at this moment

Comment: For me it seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/167/ if you want dynamic div to be inserted, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202998/vue-event-handler-on-dynamically-inserted-string-does-not-work/47203778#47203778

Comment: actually this might be simpler solution to embed html tags https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/170/

Comment: @samayo Thanks you! I solved this problem with your tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<template>
  <div v-if='requestCompleted'>
    <div v-if='!postResult'> Fail </div>
    <div v-else-if='postResult'> Success </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true; // Send as 
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      name : "",
      postResult : null,
      requestCompleted: false
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {

      this.$http.post('/api/test',   {name:this.name}).then((response)=>{
        var result = response.data;
        this.requestCompleted=true;
        if (result.name == "1234")
        {
          this.postResult = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
          this.postResult = false;
      }
    }, function(response){
      // Error Handling
    });
  }
}
});
</script>
```

Use arrow functions for getting access to  'this' inside your callback function.

For HTTP requests, it's better to use Axios. Also, you can use vuex store and manage your requests with actions

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "this" inside your response callback. Do `var me = this` at the top level of your click function, then do `me.postResult = ...` in the callback.

In general terms, try and keep all your markup in the template element, no ?