# Vue - Dynamic component event listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-dynamic-components

**Problem** : I am trying to create a `table` component for my app which would be use by other components to render a table. It could have three possible cell values :

- Text
- HTML
- Component

I am able to render all the above values but I am stuck at binding an `event` listener. What I am trying to achieve is something like this :
Pass a method and event which is to be binded to the component and the table should bind that with respective cell.
So for example :

**TABLE JSON**

```
{
   "cell-1":{
      "type":"html",
      "data":"<h4>text-1</h4>",
      "method": someMethod
   }
}
```

**TABLE COMPONENT**

```
  <tbody>
   <template>
      <tr>
         <td  >
            <span
               v-if="type == 'html'"
               v-html="data"
               v-on:click.native="$emit(someMethod)"
               v-on:click.native="someMethod"
               ></span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </template>
</tbody>
```

Above is just a snippet of what I am trying, the table loops through the object passed and renders accordingly.

I have already tried

- [SO Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component)
- [SO Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202998/vue-event-handler-on-dynamically-inserted-string-does-not-work)

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to have the method/handler inside the parent component and then trigger is using the emit functionality such that in

**TABLE COMPONENT**

```
  <tbody>
   <template>
      <tr>
         <td  >
            <span
               v-if="type == 'html'"
               v-html="data"
               v-on:click.native="$emit('trigger-handler', {method: 'method1', data: {}})"
               ></span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </template>
</tbody>
```

and in

**Parent.vue**

```
<table-component @trigger-handler="triggerHandler" />
```

inside script

```
export default {
 data() {
 },
 methods: {
  triggerHandler(payload) {
   // payload is actually the object passed from the child
   this[payload.method](payload.data); // call a specific method
  },
  method1(data) {
  },
  method2(data) {
  },
  method3(data) {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: so traditional prop passing? If I have a lot of methods then this would be a problem right. Had already thought of this tho

Comment: Its pretty easy...you don't need to pass all the methods. Pls check the edited answer

Comment: let me try that.

Comment: did that work??